# Why does fluent nHibernate throw a NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I use this query to search for a name in a SQL Server database via fluent nHibernate:

```cs
var content = (from person in DBSession.Query<Person>() 
               where
               (PersonenBezeichnungsGenerator.BuildName(person.FirstName, person.FamilyName).ToUpper() == contaktperson.ToUpper()) //This throws a NotSupportedException
               //((person.FirstName+ " " + person.FamilyName).ToUpper() == contaktperson.ToUpper()) //This works
               select person).ToList();
```

This is the function BuildName:

```cs
public static string BuildName(string firstName, string familyName)
{
    return familyName + " " + firstName;
}
```

When I run this nHibernate throws a NotSupportedException. Why is this?

> System.NotSupportedException
> HResult=0x80131515
> Message=System.String BuildName(System.String, System.String)
> Source=NHibernate

Is there any way to use functions like this in a fluent nHibernate query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NotSupportedException` is thrown because the LINQ provider for NHibernate does not know how to translate your custom function `PersonenBezeichnungsGenerator.BuildName()` into SQL.

When using LINQ to query with NHibernate, the provider inspects the LINQ expression tree at runtime and tries to translate it into a regular SQL expression.

In your case, you could probably do this:

```cs
var allPersons = DBSession.Query<Person>().ToList();
var content = allPersons
                .Where(person => PersonenBezeichnungsGenerator.BuildName(person.FirstName, person.FamilyName).ToUpper() == contaktperson.ToUpper())
                .ToList();
```

Be aware that this approach fetches all the Person records from the database before filtering, which may not be the best solution large datasets.

Comment: Is there a way to make my function translatable into sql?

Comment: @Gener4tor, yes LINQKit can do that, but it needs additional steps.